# Convert Attributes to Tag in java

Tags: java, xml, xstream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert all node's attributes into child nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340272/convert-all-nodes-attributes-into-child-nodes)

I would like to convert xml attributes to tag. for e.g. Using XStream

```
    <root>
       <abc attr1="aaa" attr2="bbb"/>
    </root>
```

TO

```
    <root>
       <abc>
         <attr1>aaa</attr1>
         <attr2>bbb</attr2>
       </abc>
    </root>
```

Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: XStream is not the tool for this job. XStream is an object binding framework. This is a job for XSLT.

Comment: I have never used XSLT, can you please point me to a sample link if you have any?

Comment: Google for `xslt "convert attributes to elements"`, plenty hits there

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340272/convert-all-nodes-attributes-into-child-nodes/4340406#4340406

Comment: Why not use XOM instead? It's easier to understand :). Just my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to convert it directly as long as XStream is used. If you want to use XStream, it is necessary to make the class that corresponds to the element of XML.

[to read]

```
XStream xs = new XStream(new DomDriver());
xs.alias("root", ParentElement.class);
xs.useAttributeFor(ChildElement.class, "aaa"); // read as attribute
xs.useAttributeFor(ChildElement.class, "bbb");

ParentElement parent = new ParentElement();
try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("readfile");
    xs.fromXML(fis, parent);
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

[to write]

```
ChildElement element = new ChildElement();
element.setAttr1("aaa");
element.setAttr2("bbb");

ParentElement parent = new ParentElement();
parent.setChildElement(element);

XStream xs = new XStream();
xs.alias("root", ParentElement.class);

try {
    FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("writefile");
    xs.toXML(parent, fs);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

[ParentElement]

```
public class ParentElement {
    private ChildElement abc;
    public void setChildElement(ChildElement child) {
        this.abc = child;
    }
}
```

[ChildElement]

```
public class ChildElement {
    private String attr1;
    private String attr2;

    public String getAttr1() {
        return attr1;
    }
    public void setAttr1(String attr1) {
        this.attr1 = attr1;
    }

    public String getAttr2() {
        return attr2;
    }
    public void setAttr2(String attr2) {
        this.attr2 = attr2;
    }
}
```