# Convert XML Attributes To Elements XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to convert attributes to sub-elements, ie turn the following:

```
<WP featured="yes" player="no" dancers="no" series="logos" archive="no" fanart="no" id="eclipse_logos_">
    <seriesName>LOGOS</seriesName>
    <selection>ECLIPSE</selection>
    <imgurl>http://www.nba.com/warriors/photos/eclipse_logos_</imgurl>
    <res>1024x1024r(iPad/iPhone)?1280x1024r(Regular)?1440x900r(Widescreen)?1920x1080r(HDTV)?1920x1200r(Widescreen)</res>
</WP>
```

Into:

```
<WP>
    <featured>yes</featured>
    <player>no</player>
    <dancers>no</dancers>
    <series>logos</series>
    <archive>no</archive>
    <fanart>no></fanart>
    <id>eclipse_logos_</id>
    <seriesName>LOGOS</seriesName>
    <selection>ECLIPSE</selection>
    <imgurl>http://www.nba.com/warriors/photos/eclipse_logos_</imgurl>
    <res>1024x1024r(iPad/iPhone)?1280x1024r(Regular)?1440x900r(Widescreen)?1920x1080r(HDTV)?1920x1200r(Widescreen)</res>
</WP>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert all node's attributes into child nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340272/convert-all-nodes-attributes-into-child-nodes)

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: hi, sorry for the lag in my reply. maybe I'm applying your xslt style sheet incorrectly because all I get is a blank page when I open the xml file in my browser. I saved your code as wallpaper.xsl and then put `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="wallpaper.xsl"?>` at the top of my xml document. is this incorrect?

Comment: What browser did you use? I tested with Chrome and IE 9, both locally (as local files) and remotely (on the web server). Chrome didn't like opening the local file (it was blank) and the console (CTRL+SHIFT+J) displayed this message: `Unsafe attempt to load URL file:///... from frame with URL file:///.... Domains, protocols and ports must match.` Opening remotely worked on both.

Comment: To @infant-programmeraravind's point, although this solution does work, it's pretty broad.  If the source XML had any other attributes outside the `<WP>` element, they would be converted to elements, too.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit the logic behind the code mentioned above for those who are not familiar with XSLT?

Answer (score 3):

dradu's code is generic, the transformation will be applicable to all the attributes,
below code is more specific about WP element: only those attributes coming under WP element will be converted to elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="WP/@*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```