# How to transform an xml document and insert additional data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt

I have an xml document in this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<person name="Bob" addr_street="123 Fake St" 
        addr_city="Springfield" addr_state="IL"/>
```

I would like to take this data and run it through a `FigureOutZipCode(string city, string state)` function in my code.

I would then like to take all of this combined data and create a new document in this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<people>
    <person>
        <name>Bob</name>
        <address>
            <street>123 Fake St</address>
            <city>Springfield</city>
            <state>IL</state>
            <zip>00000</zip>
        </address>
    </person>
</people>
```

I know I could just parse all of the data from the input xml, do my calculations, and then create a new output xml, but is there a neater/better way to go about doing this? Something like using xslt, perhaps?

And if so, could you provide me with some guidance on how to do that?

Comment: For xslt, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645359/convert-xml-attributes-to-elements-xslt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you would do this with XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:custom="custom-functions">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/person">
    <people>
      <xsl:copy>
        <name>
          <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        </name>
        <address>
          <street>
            <xsl:value-of select="@addr_street"/>
          </street>
          <city>
            <xsl:value-of select="@addr_city"/>
          </city>
          <state>
            <xsl:value-of select="@addr_state"/>
          </state>
          <zip>
            <xsl:value-of
              select="custom:figureOutZipCode(@addr_city, @addr_state)"/>
          </zip>
        </address>
      </xsl:copy>
    </people>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In .NET, calling the `figureOutZipCode()` function would typically involve passing an XSLT extension object to the XSLT processor, which is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltargumentlist.addextensionobject.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, with XSLT you can transform your original XML and output a new (transformed) XML file using the same XSLT sheet, if you use the `result-document` instruction. This requires the Saxon .NET XSLT parser, available here: http://saxon.sourceforge.net/

Info on using `result-document` here: http://saxonica.com/documentation9.4-demo/html/xsl-elements/result-document.html

For learning XSLT, I recommend anything by Michael Kay (who created Saxon), for example: [http://www.amazon.com/XSLT-Programmers-Reference-Michael-Kay/dp/1861003129](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1861003129)

Comment: See also, the XslCompiledTransform class in MSDN (includes example): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ to transform your XML into the new format

```
string URL = @"location";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(URL);

XElement newDoc = new XElement("people",
            from p in doc.Descendants("person")
            select new XElement("person", 
                new XElement("name", p.Attribute("name").Value),
                new XElement("address",
                    new XElement("street", p.Attribute("addr_street").Value),
                    new XElement("city", p.Attribute("addr_city").Value),
                    new XElement("state", p.Attribute("addr_state").Value),
                    new XElement("zip", GetZip(parameters))
                    )
            )
            );
```

Comment: From question: `I know I could just parse all of the data from the input xml, do my calculations, and then create a new output xml, but is there a neater/better way to go about doing this? Something like using xslt, perhaps?`