# How to convert XML element names using the element's attribute value with XSLT?

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

I am working on an XML dataset, however I am not quite sure how to convert it to my desired format using XSLT so I can work with it. Currently I have an XML with element's that aren't useful to me and name attributes which hold the names of what the elements should actually be named after. So currently an element is called `<L7j:col>` whilst I'd want it to be named after the 'name' attribute, for example `<firstname>`.
Could anyone please help me with this?

**Current (example) XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<L7j:jdbcQueryResult xmlns:L7j="http://ns.l7tech.com/2012/08/jdbc-query-result">
    <L7j:row>
        <L7j:col name="firstname">Stefan</L7j:col>
        <L7j:col name="lastname">McLovin</L7j:col>
        <L7j:col name="age" type="java.lang.String">21</L7j:col>
        <L7j:col name="year" type="java.math.BigDecimal">3</L7j:col>
        <L7j:col name="id">0001</L7j:col>
    </L7j:row>
    <L7j:row>
        <L7j:col name="firstname">Kevin</L7j:col>
        <L7j:col name="lastname">McCool</L7j:col>
        <L7j:col name="age" type="java.lang.String">25</L7j:col>
        <L7j:col name="year" type="java.math.BigDecimal">4</L7j:col>
        <L7j:col name="id">0002</L7j:col>
    </L7j:row>
</L7j:jdbcQueryResult>
```

**The XSLT I found to convert the XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:L7j="https://ns.l7tech.com/2012/08/jdbc-query-result">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                <xsl:element name="{name()}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645359/convert-xml-attributes-to-elements-xslt)

**Current Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<L7j:jdbcQueryResult xmlns:L7j="https://ns.l7tech.com/2012/08/jdbc-query-result">
    <L7j:row>
        <L7j:col>
            <name>firstname</name>Stefan</L7j:col>
        <L7j:col>
            <name>lastname</name>Meeuwessen</L7j:col>
        <L7j:col>
            <name>age</name>
            <type>java.lang.String</type>21</L7j:col>
        <L7j:col>
            <name>year</name>
            <type>java.math.BigDecimal</type>3</L7j:col>
        <L7j:col>
            <name>id</name>0001</L7j:col>
    </L7j:row>
    <L7j:row>
        <L7j:col>
            <name>firstname</name>Kevin</L7j:col>
        <L7j:col>
            <name>lastname</name>Meeuwessen</L7j:col>
        <L7j:col>
            <name>age</name>
            <type>java.lang.String</type>25</L7j:col>
        <L7j:col>
            <name>year</name>
            <type>java.math.BigDecimal</type>4</L7j:col>
        <L7j:col>
            <name>id</name>0002</L7j:col>
    </L7j:row>
</L7j:jdbcQueryResult>
```

**Desired output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<L7j:jdbcQueryResult xmlns:L7j="http://ns.l7tech.com/2012/08/jdbc-query-result">
    <L7j:row>
        <firstname>Stefan</firstname>
        <lastname>Meeuwessen</lastname>
        <age>21</age>
        <year>3</year>
        <id>0001</id>
    </L7j:row>
    <L7j:row>
        <firstname>Kevin</firstname>
        <lastname>Meeuwessen</lastname>
        <age>25</age>
        <year>4<year>
        <id>0002</id>
    </L7j:row>
</L7j:jdbcQueryResult>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you want can be produced by:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:L7j="http://ns.l7tech.com/2012/08/jdbc-query-result">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="L7j:col">
        <xsl:element name="{@name}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Pay attention to the `xmlns:L7j` namespace declaration. In your input (and in my stylesheet) it is:

```
xmlns:L7j="http://ns.l7tech.com/2012/08/jdbc-query-result"
```

but in your stylesheet it is:

```
xmlns:L7j="https://ns.l7tech.com/2012/08/jdbc-query-result"
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This indeed answers my question :)

Comment: Good answer. I just added `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` to remove not needed whitespaces.